# How i can show the share menu in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, ios8

I'm developing an App which needs share information in the principal social networks (twitter, facebook, twenty...). And I need to show the share menu (http://img.applesfera.com/2013/08/ios7beta5-twitter.jpg)

Another Question, I need to do the share manually or there are another way to do that (can iOS automatically do that??)

Thanks a lot.

I import Facebook SDK

import FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h

Comment: There are lot of things to do with that FacebookSDK. Please read well before asking question, save your reputation. Refer this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share

Comment: This question is too broad.  What have you tried already?  Show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

You can find various share menu on [coco-controls Menu](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=menu).

Below is one of them.

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/stackmenu.

For Sharing you have to use Facebook,twitter and others SDK.You can find many tutorials for this.